# Finding n0 in big O notation

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

This is a continuation of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411786/confused-on-big-o-notation/34415412#34415412). I learned how to validate if the relationship holds for

```
3n2 − 100n + 6 = O(n2),
```

because I choose `c = 3` and `3n2 > 3n2 − 100n + 6`;

specifically if `c = 1` and `n0` is `0.06`, if n is greater than 0.06, say `n = 5`,

```
5^2 = 25 > 3*5^2 − (100*5) + 6 = -469
```

Now, it seems I am unable to apply the same method with the following equation.

```
3n2 − 100n + 6 = O(n3), because I choose c = 1 and n3 > 3n2 − 100n + 6 when n > 3;
```

What bothers me is the "when n > 3" part, suppose `n = 2`

```
f(n) - 3*2^2 − (100*2) + 6 = -182

f(g) - 2^3 = 8

8 > -182
```

The relationship still holds!

I think I am making a mistake somewhere because I have not been able to satisfy myself that the relation will only hold when `n > 3`. What should I do?

Comment: That is why the definition says `for n>n0`. It doesn't matter if it holds for `n<n0`. As long as there is `n0` to satisfy that condition, the definition requirements are fulfilled. You can say `n0=3, n0=100` or anything else, greater than `0.06`.

Comment: @ndn I think it's no longer 0.06. I understand the problem earlier, but now having trubble with the new one "3n2 − 100n + 6 = O(n3), because I choose c = 1 and n3 > 3n2 − 100n + 6 when n > 3;". I'm bothered with the "when n > 3", because I tried if n = 2 the relation still holds? That is, 8 > -182 (please see at the end of the question). This time the book provides the value of n0, but I can't convince myself that the relation can't be true if n <= n0 (3).

Comment: sorry, didn't see the new question was about `O(n^3)`. The same logic still applies.

Comment: @ndn but why n > 3? It's still true if n < 3 E.G. n = 2, right?

Comment: `n>3` is just an example. You can use any `n0`, as long as the condition holds true. For example `n0 = -100` won't cut it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've written in [my answer to your question in the previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411786/confused-on-big-o-notation/34419205#34419205), the set of constants (c, n0) that fulfils

```
f(n) < c · g(n), for all n > n0,                         (+)
```

**is not unique**. Also, you needn't find the "highest" n>n0 to show asymptotic behaviour, but rather any n0 that shows whatever asymptotic relation you want to prove. Recall that since we're interested in the *asymptotic behaviour*, we don't really care about how the function (or algorithm) behaves for small values of n (say n=2 or n=3).

Also, Big-O describes an **upper bound** on the asymptotic behaviour of a function (or algorithm), but it needn't be the best or tightest bound. E.g.,

```
f(n) = 3n^2 - 100n + 6

    f(n) is in O(n^2) (as shown in previous thread)        (i)
    f(n) is in O(n^3) (as shown in your question here)     (ii)
```

Here, we can show both (i) and (ii), but the former provides a tighter bound for the asymptotic behaviour of f(n) than the latter. Usually, we want to find an Big-O bound that is as tight as possible, but in practice, sometimes a good enough bound is sufficient. Consider the following situation:

- Consider we have some function or algorithm f(n). Moreover, say there is a huge effort in showing whether this f(n) is in O(n^2) or not, whereas showing that f(n) is in O(n^3) is readily done in a few minutes. Then say your boss needs to know if your algorithm performs at least "better" than n^3 asymptotically: hence, showing that f(n) is in O(n^3) suffices. Most likely, in this case, your employer would not wish for you to spend the full afternoon showing that f(n) is, in fact, ever "better" than n^2 asymptotically.

---

At your request I'll add an explanation of how to show that f(n) is in O(n^3), and why the (non-unique) choice of constant c=3 makes sense (= easily obtained)

**Problem:** Show that `f(n) = 3n2 − 100n + 6` is in `O(n3)`

We'll use an approach similar to the one in the [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411786/confused-on-big-o-notation/34419205#34419205).

Let's describe your functions as a sum of it's highest term and another function

```
f(n) = 3n^2 + h(n)                                       (*)
h(n) = 6 - 100n                                          (**)
```

In the previous thread we showed, quite readily, that (I just list results here)

```
    => h(n) < 0, given n > 6/100                         (i)
    => f(n) < 3*n^2, given n > 6/100                     (ii)
```

Now, consider the following function

```
g(n) = n^3                                               (***)
```

What can we say about this function in terms of `3*n^2`, using also results (i-ii) above?

```
for n = 3: g(3) = 3^3 = 3*3^2 > f(3) ((ii): since n = 3 > 6/100)
hence,    

   =>  for n > 3: g(n) > f(n)                            (iii)
```

Now, we reached (iii) quite easily since already had result (ii), which in turn, were also reached quite easily. Hence, the choice of `n0=3` comes quite naturally. Also, note that (iii) exactly describes the relation (+), but with constant `c=1`; hence choosing c as 1.

Hence, we've shown that (+) holds for constant set **(c,n0) = (1,3)**, and subsequently, *f(n) is in O(n^3)*.

---

Again, we could possibly find a lower value of `n0` by directly attacking the problem *"for which smallest value of n0 does 'n^2 - 100n + 6 < n^3, n>n0' hold?"*, but we're not really interested in this: we want to look at the asymptotic behaviour of the function we study.

Hence, **any** constant set `(c,n0)` that helps us to show (+) **suffices**, and any further work in finding other constant sets (with smaller n0 values, and so on) could perhaps be a valuable exercise in algebra, but not of value for our analysis of the asymptotic behaviour of f(n).

Comment: what about the way I came up with comparing the two functions? That is, the way I just substituted n like "f(n) - 3*2^2 − (100*2) + 6", how does it compare with the method you described in the previous thread?

Comment: @morbidCode in the last "code box" in your question above, you are doing a point-comparison between two functions (comparing their values at specific point). This cannot really be used to say anything regarding their asymptotic behaviour, as a point-local investigation says little about a functions behaviour at all. Regarding your second question in the comment above: I'll edit in an example of analysing the function w.r.t. O(n^3).

Comment: thanks for this! I would like to know since you already mentioned something about algebra. What algebra skills do I need to solve these kinds of problems? I see you used linear inequalities to find n where equation -100n+6 = 0, is that correct?

Comment: @morbidCode You're welcome, good luck with your coding and Big-O studies!

Comment: thanks. Ah, regarding my big-O studies. I have a follow up question, one that I think will help me decide to continue. Do you mind answering it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421620/role-of-lower-order-terms-in-big-o-notation thanks again!

Comment: sure, I'll look at it.